# Using function map() to updatemask with two imagenCollections

Tags: google-earth-engine

```
function ActMask(ListaDeImagenes,index){
    return ee.Image(ListaDeImagenes)
        .updateMask(ee.Image(mascara_lista.get(index)));
}
```

I want to use this function to updatemask two imageCollections, but it returns an error. It doesn't seem to read index correctly as index.

How can I perform batch operations ‘updateMask’ on two imageCollections that are images and masks respectively?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example that shows the error you encounter? ee.Image(listaDeImagenes) is not going to work, you can't provide the entire list to the ee.Image() call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ee.ImageCollection` is not a JavaScript array. The function you pass to `map()` will be called with a single argument, an `ee.Image`. You also cannot use `get()` to extract images by index from the collection. That function extract properties by key.

Not knowing the specifics of your case - you didn't provide a complete example - it's a bit hard to suggest how you solve this. I would suggest that you look into [joins](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/joins_intro). If the images in both collections have a common key, you can join them together. Here's an example joining by `system:index`:

```
var cloudThreshold = 30
var filter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.bounds(Map.getBounds(true)),
  ee.Filter.date('2019-03-01', '2019-03-31')
)

var images = ee.ImageCollection(
    ee.Join.saveFirst('cloudProbability').apply({
        primary: ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR').filter(filter),
        secondary: ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY').filter(filter),
        condition: ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'system:index', rightField: 'system:index'})
    })
).map(function (image) {
  var cloudFree = ee.Image(image.get('cloudProbability')).lt(cloudThreshold)
  return image.updateMask(cloudFree)
})

Map.addLayer(images.median(), {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', max: 3000, gamma: 1.5})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/493ea55c5e09ed91b03491b731cbe4e5

Alternatively, you can map over your images and find the corresponding mask image yourself, based on some property, `system:index` in this example:

```
var cloudThreshold = 30
var filter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.bounds(Map.getBounds(true)),
  ee.Filter.date('2019-03-01', '2019-03-31')
)

var cloudProbabilities = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY')
var images = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filter(filter)
  .map(function (image) {
    var cloudFree = cloudProbabilities
      .filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', image.get('system:index')))
      .first()
      .lt(cloudThreshold)    
    return image.updateMask(cloudFree)
  })

Map.addLayer(images.median(), {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', max: 3000, gamma: 1.5})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/eb675eb43514b8d3c06819b59fd1fd69

Finally, and generally a bad idea, would be to turn the collections into lists, and `zip()` them together. This relies on both collections being in the exact same order. Turning collections to lists will cost you memory and processing time. Try to solve your problem using the other approaches, if at all possible. Start with the join.

```
var cloudThreshold = 30
var filter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.bounds(Map.getBounds(true)),
  ee.Filter.date('2019-03-01', '2019-03-31')
)

var cloudProbabilities = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY')
  .filter(filter)
  .toList(1e6)
var images = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filter(filter)
  .toList(1e6)

var masked = ee.ImageCollection(
  images.zip(cloudProbabilities)
    .map(function (tuple) {
      tuple = ee.List(tuple)
      var image = ee.Image(tuple.get(0))
      var cloudProbability = ee.Image(tuple.get(1))
      var cloudFree = cloudProbability.lt(cloudThreshold)    
      return image.updateMask(cloudFree)
    })
)
Map.addLayer(masked.median(), {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', max: 3000, gamma: 1.5})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b80ed4c9593e396a2becc7a674e8e503

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem was that I initially used a for statement to run the updatemask function to updatemask the two imageCollections. But if I use the map function instead of the for function, I can't use an index like i to call the corresponding objects in the 2 imageCollections at the same time.
The reason I can't use the for function is that it returns an error when the amount of data is very large, up to a dozen years of data. i give you a link about my code:https://code.earthengine.google.com/e2fe10cb38c990b0ca180489aec7ea2f
Your example seems useful, thanks a lot.

Comment: If you have better suggestions for my program, please leave a message.